validate json schema using NjsonSchema with ref field
I tried to validate this schema using NjsonSchema but I getting error like ": 'Could not resolve the JSON path '/defs/product' because no document path is available.'"
this is my main-schema-json file:
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Image",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
        "identifier",
        "altText",
        "products",
      ],
  "properties": {
    "identifier": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Image identifier"
    },
    "altText": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "image alt text"
    },
    "products": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "list of products with markers",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "/defs/product"
      }
    }
  }
}

this is my common json file:
{
 "$id": "https://inter-ikea.atlassian.net/defs/product",
 "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
 "title": "Product",
 "type": "object",
 "required": [
    "dot",
 ],
 "properties": {
   "dot": {
     "title": "Dot coordinates and product",
     "type": "object",
     "required": [
       "top",
       "left"
     ],
     "top": {
       "type": "number",
       "description": "0-1 distance from top"
     },
     "left": {
       "type": "number",
       "description": "0-1 distance from left"
     }
   }
 }

this is my code:
using JsonSchema = NJsonSchema.JsonSchema;
string mainSchemaJson = File.ReadAllText("../../.././ImageSchema.json");

var schema = await JsonSchema.FromJsonAsync(mainSchemaJson);


Don't use FromJsonAsync use FromFileAsync
code:
var schema = await JsonSchema.FromFileAsync("../../.././ImageSchema.json");

string json = @"
        {
            ""personInfo"": {
                ""name"": ""John"",
                ""age"": 30
            },
            ""contactInfo"": {
                ""email"": ""john@example.com"",
                ""address"": ""123 Street""
            }
        }";
var validationErrors = schema.Validate(json); // Validate

if (validationErrors.Count == 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Validation successful.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Validation errors:");
    foreach (var error in validationErrors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"- {error}");
    }
}

mainschema.json:
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "title": "Image",
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
        "identifier",
        "altText",
        "products",
      ],
  "properties": {
    "identifier": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Image identifier"
    },
    "altText": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "image alt text"
    },
    "products": {
      "type": "array",
      "title": "list of products with markers",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "./products.json"
      }
    }
  }
}



this variation may work if the mainschema and products files are in the same directory because the ./ relative reference can be resolved.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

@JeremyFiel I already put that file same directory

You don't have an $id (base uri) defined in the main schema which makes this an anonymous schema. That introduces the problem you are having, no base uri is defined to resolve the relative reference.
you can read more about that here:
https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring#dollarref
